# How to convert curl command to http put request

Tags: javascript, curl

I have a curl command "`curl -X PUT -F 'image=@image1.jpeg' https://someurl`"
and I want to convert that to https put request. But I am getting

> 405:Method not allowed error

code 
Javascript :

```
$( function() {
      var imgElem = document.getElementById('img');
      $('#urlText').keyup(function(){
      $('#img').attr('src',$('#urlText').val());

      $('#sendData').click(function(){
      var imgData = JSON.stringify(getBase64Image(imgElem));
      $.ajax({
      url: 'https://someurl',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: imgData,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      }
     });
    });

    function getBase64Image(imgElem) {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = imgElem.clientWidth;
      canvas.height = imgElem.clientHeight;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      imgElem.onload = function(){
      ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
      };
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message!

Comment: The objvious difference between the curl command and jQuery is that you use POST, it probably doesn't work (upload files is usually multipart form data) but you could try: `type: 'PUT',`

Comment: PUT != POST. They are different HTTP methods. Hence why you get "method not allowed".

Comment: Even with put it does not work

Comment: same error or something else? "does not work" is not a useful description of your problem. note what HMR said about how you're dong the upload

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys It was a CORS issue which made the api give 405 error. I used chrome in security disabled mode to make it work.

Comment: "I used chrome in security disabled mode to make it work.". Ok but how's that going to work when you make this live to users?